# How to calculate deviations from weighted mean in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to calculate deviations from (weighted) mean for many variables in a `data.table`.

Let's take this example set:

```r
mydt <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    x = 1:6,
    y = 6:1,
    w = rep(1:2, 3)
)

mydt
   id x y w
1:  1 1 6 1
2:  2 2 5 2
3:  2 3 4 1
4:  3 4 3 2
5:  3 5 2 1
6:  3 6 1 2
```

I can calculate the weighted means of `x` and `y` as follows:

```r
mydt[
    ,
    lapply(
        as.list(.SD)[c("x", "y")], 
        weighted.mean, w = w
    ),
    by = id
]
```

(I use the relatively complicated `as.list(.SD)[...]` construct instead of `.SDcols` because of [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) bug.)

I tried to first create the means for each row, but did not find how to combine `:=` with `lapply()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tweak the weighted mean calculation a bit:

```r
mydt[
    ,
    lapply(
        .SD[, .(x, y)], 
        function(var) var - weighted.mean(var, w = w)
    ),
    by = id
]

   id       x       y
1:  1  0.0000  0.0000
2:  2 -0.3333  0.3333
3:  2  0.6667 -0.6667
4:  3 -1.0000  1.0000
5:  3  0.0000  0.0000
6:  3  1.0000 -1.0000
```

The solution is updated by the suggested notational simplification of @DavidArenburg.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks. It is simpler indeed but also loses the original variable names, you get `V1` and `V2` instead of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Then `.SD[, .(x, y)]` ?

Comment: for easier programmatic use you can always provide character vector of columns names to keep: `.SD[, c("x","y"), with=FALSE]`.